# MYSQL: Aborted connection to db: 'unconnected' user: debian-sys-maint' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)

Tags: mysql, timeout, localhost, percona

I recently migrated all my logs to a new service, where I could see a recurring bug in mysql.

The message is the following:

`Aborted connection <NUM> to db: 'unconnected' user: debian-sys-maint' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)`

Where `<NUM>` is some connection id.

I'm not sure if it has to do with a recent change I made, where I migrated my database from mysql to percona server 5.7. My host has Debian 8.7

I don't know what script/cron job is triggered... but all my websites has no problems connecting to same database (all services are hosted in the same VPS).

Any idea? 
I tried increasing the value of max_allowed_packet, now is 128M but still  happening.

Comment: check if you have the debian-sys-maint user and check contents of /etc/mysql/debian.cnf?

Comment: **debian-sys-maint** user exists, the password in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf, match, I can login using mysql cli.